# WPF : How to assign click event to the form

Tags: wpf, canvas, mouseclick-event

How to assign Click event in this? I want to do something when mouse click on this window.
It's doesn't have Click properties in both Window and Canvas

```
<Window Loaded="Window_Loaded"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  x:Class="InClassApp.UI.TextNotify"
  x:Name="Window"
  Title="TextNotify"
  Width="400" Height="100"
  WindowStyle="None"
  AllowsTransparency="True"
  Background="Transparent"
  ShowInTaskbar="False">
  <Border CornerRadius="5">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFBAFDFF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
       <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        .......
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you might want to add `MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"` on your `<Window>` element.

and add following in the code-behind file.

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuff here.
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest handling the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event instead of `MouseLeftButtonDown`, because that's the way the `Click` event is implemented, i.e. users might be confused if the event is raised *before* they release the mouse button.

Comment: I agree with Frederic here.  As a user in any application, I rely on this little detail of UI processing to avoid clicking on the wrong UI element.  Often enough, I click the wrong thing, and to avoid triggering a process I would rather not trigger, I keep the button held until I move the cursor away from the element.  It has become second nature.  I would be quite unhappy if an application triggered immediately when I pressed the button.

Answer (score 15):

You could handle the [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event instead.